# Connecting to a specific chat server URL with Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

for an assignment, I am building a chat app with Socket.io. I was able to do so by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHbCkikFfDE. However, for the assignment, I have to use a provided chat server which I am unsure how to do. I was provided with a chat service endpoint which looks like: "https://xxxxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com" as well as an event name which looks like: "xxxxx/chat". I'm very new to JavaScript and I'm struggling to figure out where/how to implement this.

Because I was following a video tutorial, this is how I began my server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var users = [];
var connections = [];
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

I've seen other posts where people connect to a certain IP address but I cannot find any where URLs are used. How might I approach this?

Comment: to summarise your question, do you mean to ask "How do I connect my Socket.IO server to an endpoint server?"

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant @YongQuan

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your server is running. If it is in your localhost then the IP must be like `var client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/', 'echo-protocol');`. This is an example using websocket.

If you are using socket.io then it must be like `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io('http://localhost');
</script>`

that's why I said the connecting url depends on your server.

You can take a look at this [link](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/)

Comment: I believe that my server is running on my localhost. To connect and view my chat room, I have been putting http://localhost:3000/ in my browser. If this is the case, how would I implement the chat service endpoint which looks like: "https://xxxxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com"?

Comment: I hope you know what is heroku. If you deploy your app in heroku you can implement your chat service end point like xxxxx.herokuapp.com, the **xxxxxx** indicate your app name in heroku

Comment: I am trying to send and receive messages to and from an existing chat server. I was already given the url of the chat server (I used xxxxxxxxxx to keep it anonymous but there is an already existent chat server).

Comment: If you want to use existing chat server, then you connect with that server at your client side. A few lines of code is needed to connect with the server.
For example,
`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io('http://xxxx.herokuapp.com');
</script>`
This example is for javascript client